# How can i upload file from console with other data

Tags: java, objectoutputstream, sendfile

I would like to upload file to my web server.
My server implement RESTful API.
To upload file i should pass 4 parameters: file, file_name, project, version

I would like to upload file with this 3 parameters from console. I tried this

```
URL obj = new URL(MY_URL);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("POST");

con.setDoOutput(true);

ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
ToSend send = new ToSend();
send.file = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("path"));
send.file_name  = "name";
send.project = "test";
send.version = "1";
objectOutputStream.writeObject(send);
objectOutputStream.flush();
objectOutputStream.close();
```

and the object i send look like this

```
class ToSend implements Serializable {
    byte[] file;

    String file_name;

    String project;

    String version;
}
```

I get `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:`

If this is important my server written in Java+Spring and method for this has next signature

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Response<Boolean> upload(
    @RequestParam("project") String project,
    @RequestParam("version") String version,
    @RequestParam("file_name") String fileName,
    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
) throws ServiceException, BadFileExtension {
    boolean success = storageService.uploadFile(file, project, fileName, version);

    return builder.get(success);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solutions works for me. Maybe useful for someone too.

http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically